# State will not Update when using createAsyncThunk and Redux Toolkit

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

When using `createAsyncThunk` to obtain data from my API, I can read the data, but the state will not update.

I created a slice in my file `userSlice.js`, like so

`userSlice.js`:

```
export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/fetchUserById',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    let response;
    try {
      response = await API.getUser, { userID: userId }));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    return response.data.getUser
  }
);

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {user: {}},
  reducers: {},
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUserById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      }
    });
  }
});

export default userSlice.reducer
```

This is my store, `store.js`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from './slices/userSlice'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userReducer
  }
})
```

I try to read the data in `AppLoadingScreen.js`

`AppLoadingScreen.js`:

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchUserById } from '../../redux/slices/userSlice';

const AppLoadingScreen = (props) => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.user)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  const cacheResources = async () => {
    dispatch(fetchUserById('00'))
      .unwrap()
      .then((result) => console.log("result: ", result))
      .then(console.log("in dispatch: ", user))
      .catch((e) => {console.log(e)});

    console.log("test: ", user);
  }

  return (
    <AppLoading
      startAsync={cacheResources}
      onFinish={() => {props.setIsReady(true)}}
      onError={console.warn}
    />
  );
}
```

Output:

```
in dispatch:  Object {}
test:  Object {}
result:  Object {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "height": 72,
  "age": 40,
}
```

In both cases, `user` does not update. Even if I change the dispatch call to instead use await, the state doesn't change.
New dispatch call:

```
const cacheResources = async () => {
  await dispatch(fetchUserById('00'));
  
  console.log("test: ", user);
}
```

New output:

```
test:  Object {}
```

I have also tried running the dispatch call outside of Expo's AppLoading component and the result is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state =` in an RTK Immer-powered reducer is never correct. Immer works by tracking *mutations* to nested fields (`state.someField =`), or returning an entirely new value from the reducer function ( `return newState`).  When you write `state =`, all that does is point the local variable named `state` at a new reference, which is neither a mutation nor returning anything.

So, as far as Immer can see, you haven't changed anything.

The simplest answer here is to write `state.user = action.payload`.

See [RTK Usage Guides: Writing Reducers with Immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) for more details.

Additionally, we specifically recommend [*not* using the word "reducer" in your state structure](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#name-state-slices-based-on-the-stored-data).  Instead, you should set up the store so that the state keys are named after the types of data, like:

```js
configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer
  }
})
```

Comment: I changed `userSlice.js` to use a return statement, instead of using `state=`. Also, I added the alias user to userReducer. When I console log user outside of the file `AppLoading.js`, I can now see the information from my API call. However, the console log inside of `AppLoading.js` remains empty. This isn't a real issue for me, but would you happen to know why this is occurring?

Comment: It looks like your promise chain is written incorrectly. You have `.then(console.log())`, but that will log _immediately_. You need to wrap that in an arrow function.  Personally I would write one `.then()` with an arrow function that has a `{ }` body and both log lines inside of it.